# Django Reserved Url Names

Tags: python, django

I have these views in my django website. I want to redirect my users to categories like

http://sitename.com/category1/

http://sitename.com/category2/

http://sitename.com/category3/

but django detects my view names like category names if i want to go watch page or register page like:

http://sitename.com/register/

http://sitename.com/watch/

django redirects me to category view. How can i fix my problem?

```
url(r'^management/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$', views.ana_sayfa),
url(r'^(.+)/', views.kategori),
url(r'^register/', views.kayit_sayfasi),
url(r'^watch/(.+)/', views.ondemand_izleme_sayfasi),
url(r'^event/(.+)/', views.live_stream_sayfasi),
url(r'^live/(.+)/', views.live_stream_izleme_sayfasi),
url(r'^buy/(.+)/', views.live_stream_satin_alma_sayfasi),
url(r'^search/(.+)/', views.arama),
url(r'^manager/', views.video_yoneticisi),
url(r'^lists/', views.listelerim),
url(r'^profile/', views.bilgilerimi_guncelle),
url(r'^messages/', views.mesajlarim),
url(r'^subscriptions/', views.abonelikler),
url(r'^settings/', views.bildirim_ayarlari),
url(r'^contact/', views.iletisim),
url(r'^help/', views.yardim),
url(r'^rss/', views.rss),
url(r'^oneall/', include('django_oneall.urls')),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your category url pattern is evaluated before the other patterns.
You could move it to the bottom, so all of the others will be evaluated first.
So move this line to the bottom:

```
url(r'^(.+)/', views.kategori),
```

See also [URL dispatching:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.

Comment: Correct. Thanks a lot my problem is solved. Sorry for question i'm newbie in Django :)

Answer (score 0):

The URL routing patterns are evaluated in order. You need to either move your category route `url(r'^(.+)/', views.kategori),` down to the bottom, as `^(.+)` matches everything with one or more letters plus a slash, or change the regular expression from `'^(.+)/'` to something like `'^(category.+)/'`.